# XML Change dynamically

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I have a problem with my XML sitemap. I want insert frequency and priority dynamically, but I don't understand the action register_sitemap

This is my code:

```
function insert_xml($content){
   global $post;
   $xml_relationship = get_field('c_page_relationship', $post->ID);
   function my_custom_post_freq($default, $url, $post_id) {
      return 'hourly';
   }
   add_filter('wpseo_sitemap_post_single_change_freq', 'my_custom_post_freq', 10, 3);

   function my_custom_post_xml_priority($default, $url, $post_id) {
      return 0.6;
   }
   add_filter('wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_priority', 'my_custom_post_xml_priority', 10, 3);

   return $xml_relationship;
}

add_action('wpseo_do_sitemap_', 'insert_xml');
```

I am using acf custom fields, to change the prority and frequency which I get from `$post_id`, the functions about this are not ready, but is the finality. I want to insert when the XML is created for yoast, I find this in the API docs yoast `wpseo_do_sitemap_<$type>` but i dont understand what is `<$type>`

> $type can not be a valid post type or taxonomy, when they are this action will not trigger

What does it need to be?

Comment: Are you sure you want to add priority and frequency? As of 3.5.0 those were removed the sitemap because they have been shown to not be used by search engines and specifically google. https://yoast.com/yoast-seo-3-5/

Comment: I commented with my team, and we decided not work with this, but for other side i want to know how make it only for fun xD thanks :D

Comment: Well in the latest versions of Yoast SEO they have removed the filters for change frequency and priority and those would have been the proper way to hook in and change something based on a post id. You would probably have to use the `wpseo_sitemap_url` filter now and remove the ending `</url>` tag, add your tags then re-add the `</url>` tag and return. The problem with that is that filter doesn't pass a post ID so you would need to try to retrieve posts by their URL.